# Change the color of a solid line in VBA

Tags: vba, colors, line, rgb

I just want to add one more line under this one, to make the line  RGB(0, 255, 0)

Sub Button1_Click()

Set My_line = Worksheets("Zadatak1").Shapes.AddLine(10, 10, 250, 250)

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
 Set My_Line = Worksheets("Zadatak1")

 With My_Line.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 10, 10, 250, 250)
  .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,255,0)
 End With

End Sub
```